# Can isc-dhcp-server and dnsmasq coexist?

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq, dhcp-server

After two days of trying to configure dhcp on dnsmasq and failing, I'd like to go back to isc-dhcp-server, and only keep dnsmasq for dns.

Can the two coexist well? is there anything I need to pay attention to while configuring?

Comment: The 2 can definitely coexist well - I use this configuration. Can't remember if I needed any config lunes in dnsmasq or if I simply load DHCPD first  so DNSMasq does not bind to the dhcp ports.

Comment: Quite late but please see this article [https://www.linux.com/tutorials/dns-and-dhcp-dnsmasq/](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/dns-and-dhcp-dnsmasq/)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but yes you can. I can only answer for recent FC/RH distributions how but the key is that by default, both dhcpd and dnsmasq will attempt to listen on all interfaces even if not declared and discard dhcpd/bootp input silently to those interfaces, creating a conflict.

On FC32, /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd is still there and has been deprecated but could be used with DHCPARGS=<listen_ifnames>, but the same file will note in the comments to instead copy /usr/lib/systemd/dhcpd.conf to /etc/systemd/system and make the change there, removing $DHCPARGS and replacing with the interface names. Don't forget to `systemctl daemon-reload` before restarting.

For dnsmasq, you would define a file in the drop in /etc/dnsmasq.d with either the listen-address or interface parameter as well as the standalone parameter "bind-interfaces" which will force it to only bind on listening interfaces. This will stop the afore-mentioned behavior and allow both to coexist.

I will add for dhcpd you can supposedly stop listening on interfaces simply not having subnet declarations for it but that did not work for me.